# Can i have a variable as a parameter for a function? javascript

Tags: javascript, function, variables, parameters

I'm trying to make a loop for 40 times using functions in javascript.

That's what i did:

```js
var i;
setTimeout(function ro(i) {
  if (i % 5 == 0) {
    currentIndex = 0;
  }
  if (i % 5 == 1) {
    currentIndex = 1;
  }
  if (i % 5 == 2) {
    currentIndex = 2;
  }
  if (i % 5 == 3) {
    currentIndex = 3;
  }
  if (i % 5 == 4) {
    currentIndex = 4;
  }
  document.getElementById('radio' + currentIndex).click();
  if (currentIndex == 5) {
    currentIndex = 0
  }
}, 2000);

for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
  ro(i);
}
```

But that's not working, because my i from ro(i) is a new parameter, i'm trying to use the same i everywhere. Is there any way to do that?
Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure how this can run. In the `for` loop, you are calling the function `ro`, but that function is not available outside the scope of the `setTimeout` closure. Where is the `40` times loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is not pass i as a parameter, but rather, keep it global. You can simply do that by defining it out of scope (like at the top of your code), and then using it inside your functions by simply calling it's name (i in this case). Below is the modified code:

```js
var i;
setTimeout(function ro() {
  if (i % 5 == 0) {
    currentIndex = 0;
  }
  if (i % 5 == 1) {
    currentIndex = 1;
  }
  if (i % 5 == 2) {
    currentIndex = 2;
  }
  if (i % 5 == 3) {
    currentIndex = 3;
  }
  if (i % 5 == 4) {
    currentIndex = 4;
  }
  document.getElementById('radio' + currentIndex).click();
  if (currentIndex == 5) {
    currentIndex = 0
  }
}, 2000);

for (i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
  ro();
}
```